# How do I clear all the rows from a table using Entity Framework Core?

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-core, entity-framework-core

New to Entity Framework Core. How do I clear all the rows from a table?

I searched around and found the following solution:

```
_context.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand("TRUNCATE TABLE[TableName]");
```

Unfortunately using `ExecuteSqlCommand` throws a compiler error.

Am I missing a namespace or is there another way to do this?

Thanks, JohnB

Comment: Hi @JohnB,have you resolve this problem? Is there any other solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`ExecuteSqlCommand` is Obsolete,you can see the details [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.entityframeworkcore.relationaldatabasefacadeextensions.executesqlcommand?view=efcore-3.1&viewFallbackFrom=efcore-5.0).

> For the execution of SQL queries using plain strings, use ExecuteSqlRaw instead. For the execution of SQL queries using interpolated string syntax to create parameters, use ExecuteSqlInterpolated instead.

So you can use:

```
 _context.Database.ExecuteSqlRaw("TRUNCATE TABLE[TableName]");
```

Comment: I do not see either ExecuteRawSQL() or ExecuteSqlCommand() as being part of the calls available from _context.Database. Am I missing a NUGet package or using statetement? Currently I have EFC, EFC.Design, EFC.Relational, and EFC.Sqlite packages installed.

Comment: I am using EFC 5.0

Comment: I've included that package, but still get compiler error: 'DatabaseFacade' does not contain a definition for 'ExecuteSQLRaw' and no accessible extension method 'ExecuteSQLRaw'

Comment: You can see [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/z01D4.png).